# IntentService, how to manage extras properly?

Tags: android, android-service

Hello I try to launch a IntentService with string as extra but it throws a null pointer exception, I search but I didnt found anything, so I ask it. Seems that the service can't extract the extras of the intent, and I don't know if is because I forget something, is the first time that I work with IntentService.

Well, in the main I throw the intent:

```
    String url = MY_HOST+"/videos/video.mp4";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideosDownloader.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    startService(intent);
```

And in the service I manage the extra:

```
public class VideosDownloader extends IntentService{


public VideosDownloader() {
    super("VideosDownloader");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("Some descrition");
        request.setTitle("Some title");

        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "video.mp4");
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        // get download service and enqueue file
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);

 }
}
```

and in the Manifest I think is everything ok, I declare as service:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name=".VideosDownloader"/>
</application>
```

The error throw is:

```
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.downloadtest.VideosDownloader@40525e50 with Intent { cmp=com.example.downloadtest/.VideosDownloader (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2073)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1006)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.IntentService.onStart(IntentService.java:110)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.IntentService.onStartCommand(IntentService.java:118)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2060)
12-19 08:45:50.482: E/AndroidRuntime(15470):    ... 10 more
```

Thanks for the reply.

SOLVED: Sorry my fault, David Wasser gave me the solution asking if I posted all code, I override Oncreate() doing nothing, and I forget that it should have super so I deleted it (because it did nothing). Thnaks for the replys!

Comment: also post the code in onStart

Comment: @TomerMor The exception occurs in `IntentService.onStart()`. This isn't OP's code, this is Android code. OP has no `onStart()` method.

Comment: actually there was till API level 3 since then there is onStartCommand, I test your code and it's work fine for me, till the onHandleIntent so try just start the service and extract the intent there

Comment: Ok I will take a look in this thanks! And I will post if I find the solution.

Comment: Something very strange going on here. Make sure you clean your project and rebuild it. Then check the logs and see if there is anything else useful in the logs. It looks like Android cannot start your service (for whatever reason). Have you posted all code of the service?

Comment: Sorry my fault, David Wasser gave me the solution asking if I posted all code, I override Oncreate() doing nothing, and I forget that it should have super so I deleted it (because it did nothing). Thanks for the replys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Sorry my fault, David Wasser gave me the solution asking if I posted all code, I override Oncreate() doing nothing, and I forget that it should have super so I deleted it (because it did nothing). Thnaks for the replys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the method `onBind`:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Because `IntentService` has an implementation of it.

Comment: I remove the Bind but it didnt work I solved it, I put the comment in my answer.